# How do I fix the base URL issue while using load balancer

Tags: 9

Since base URL is deprecated, and our Drupal 9 Site is using a load balancer, we are facing issues when setting up the base URL. Instead of the base URL, it displays the load balancer IP.

Any help regarding the issue is appreciated.

I made the following changes to the settings.php file.

```php
$settings['reverse_proxy'] = TRUE;
$settings['reverse_proxy_addresses'] = array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$settings['reverse_proxy_host_header'] = 'X-ORIGINAL-HOST';

$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = [
  '^d9\.johndoe\.dev$',
  '^10\.101\.9\.23$',
];
```

This worked for Drupal 8 but not for Drupal 9.

I followed what reported in these links.

- https://www.drupal.org/node/425990
- https://www.drupal.org/node/3030558
- https://www.drupal.org/project/trusted_reverse_proxy
- https://www.drupal.org/project/reverse_proxy_header
- https://www.58bits.com/blog/2021/02/18/canonical-urls-https-and-drupal-89-reverse-proxy-settings
- https://medium.com/@lmakarov/drupal-8-and-reverse-proxies-the-base-url-drama-c5553cbc9a3e